# Creating linked_dirs in Capistrano 3 fails

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

I am attempting to set up Capistrano with a SilverStripe build and am running into a few troubles setting up the shared directories.

I set the linked_dirs in **deploy.rb** with the following:

```
set :linked_dirs, %w{assets vendor}
```

Since adding this line I get the following error:

```
[617afa7f] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /var/www/website/releases/20160215083713 /var/www/website/releases/20160215083713
INFO [617afa7f] Finished in 0.250 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [88c3de20] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /var/www/website/releases/20160215083713/assets ] as capistrano@128.199.231.152
DEBUG [88c3de20] Command: [ -L /var/www/website/releases/20160215083713/assets ]
DEBUG [88c3de20] Finished in 0.258 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [3d61c1c4] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /var/www/website/releases/20160215083713/assets ] as capistrano@128.199.231.152
DEBUG [3d61c1c4] Command: [ -d /var/www/website/releases/20160215083713/assets ]
DEBUG [3d61c1c4] Finished in 0.254 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
INFO [3016a8cd] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /var/www/website/shared/assets /var/www/website/releases/20160215083713/assets as capistrano@128.199.231.152
```

I am a mega noob when it comes to Capistrano and a semi noob when it comes to server configuration and permissions, so any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the next line in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably hasn't actually failed. One thing to know about Capistrano is that `(success)` and `(failed)` are actually returning the result of the [exit status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status), `(success)` if 0 and `(failed)` if non-0.

If we look at the command in question, it says that `/usr/bin/env [ -L /var/www/website/releases/20160215083713/assets ]` failed. This command is saying "return 0 if `/var/www/website/releases/20160215083713/assets` exists and is a link (`-L`). This fails, but that just means it returns non-0, thus the link needs to be created. Note that the next command also fails (`-d`) with asserting that the path is a directory. And the last line in your output is actually creating the link in question.

You can see the test in the Capistrano codebase here: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/deploy.rake#L128

You can clean up and simplify the output with https://github.com/mattbrictson/airbrussh. This is developed by one of the primary Capistrano devs.

As a sidenote, similarly all the green text in your terminal is `stdout` and the red text is `stderr`. This can also be confusing.

Comment: You are correct, the assets folder was creating the link. It is extremely unsettling seeing red 'failed' text in a deployment script, happy to hear that this can be safely ignored.